# ImageMagick batch file stopped working

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

Me and another dude are trying to co-write a batch file that shall do various image operations using ImageMagick commands.

We got it to work and I decided to move it to another location on the hard drive.
All of a sudden the script doesn't work any more.

It creates the folder "modified" but do not perform the image conversions.
I can perform the convert commands from the command prompt but not by using the script.

I switched computer and after a while it happened again!

I have no clue what happened.
I have tried to:

- Move it back to the original location
- Restart the computer, as adviced by Roy in IT crowd
- Reinstalled ImageMagick
- Prayed to the IT God (who may have many names: Gates, Jobs, Thorvald, null etc)

No success whatsoever!
Please help me with any useful tips!

**Environment:**

Windows 7 64bit

ImageMagick 6.8.0-6 Q16

**The batch file has the following contents:**

```
@echo off
    :: Drag and drop a folder of images on the BAT-file.
    :: A 

    Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :: Removes the last slash if given in argument %1
    Set "Dir=%~1"
    IF "%DIR:~-1%" EQU "\" (Set "Dir=%DIR:~0,-1%")

     :: Create the output folder if don't exist
        MKDIR ".\modified" 2>NUL

  :: Set maximium image height
  SET /A "newHeight=780"

  :: Set portrate extent width
  SET /A "portrateWidth=585"

    :: Read all the png and jpg images from the directory
    FOR %%f IN ("%dir%\*.tif" "%dir%\*.jpg") DO (

        :: Set the variable width to the image width
        For /F %%# in ('identify -ping -format "%%[fx:w]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "width=%%#")

        :: Set the variable height to the image height
        For /F %%# in ('identify -ping -format "%%[fx:h]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "height=%%#")

        :: Check if the photo is portrate or landscape and run the relavant code
        IF  !height! LSS !width!  (
            convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!newHeight! "modified\%%~nf.jpg"
        ) ELSE (

  :: Only resize if height is over 780
  IF  !height! LSS !newHeight! (

            :: Calculation for portrate extent width
            SET /A "newWidth=!height! * 3/4"
            convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!height! -background blue -gravity center -extent !newWidth!x!height! "modified\%%~nf.jpg"
  ) ELSE (
   convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!newHeight! -background blue -gravity center -extent !portrateWidth!x!newHeight! "modified\%%~nf.jpg"
   )
            )
        )

PAUSE&EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

A folder dropped on the batfile never end with a slash so you can delete that part.

Try this:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: First of all sets the imagemagick directory!
PUSHD "C:\IMAGEMAGICK DIRECTORY"

:: Drag and drop a folder of images on the BAT-file.
:: A 

REM :: Removes the last slash if given in argument %1
REM Set "Dir=%~1"
REM IF "%DIR:~-1%" EQU "\" Set "Dir=%DIR:~0,-1%"

:: Create the output folder if don't exist
MKDIR "%~dp0modified" 2>NUL

:: Set maximium image height
SET /A "newHeight=780"

:: Set portrate extent width
SET /A "portrateWidth=585"

:: Read all the png and jpg images from the directory
FOR %%f IN ("%~1\*.tif" "%~1\*.jpg") DO (

    :: Set the variable width to the image width
    For /F %%# in ('identify -ping -format "%%[fx:w]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "width=%%#")

    :: Set the variable height to the image height
    For /F %%# in ('identify -ping -format "%%[fx:h]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "height=%%#")

    :: Check if the photo is portrate or landscape and run the relavant code
    IF  !height! LSS !width!  (
        convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!newHeight! "%~dp0modified\%%~nf.jpg"
    ) ELSE (

    :: Only resize if height is over 780
        IF  !height! LSS !newHeight! (
            :: Calculation for portrate extent width
            SET /A "newWidth=!height! * 3/4"
            convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!height! -background blue -gravity center -extent !newWidth!x!height! "%~dp0modified\%%~nf.jpg"
        ) ELSE (
            convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!newHeight! -background blue -gravity center -extent !portrateWidth!x!newHeight! "%~dp0modified\%%~nf.jpg"
        )
    )
)

PAUSE&EXIT
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it did not not solve my problem.
The exact same BAT file is working on a third computer that I own, and also on my co-writers computer. It has stopped working on two computers by no obivous reason.

Comment: If the same script works in other PCs then the problem appears to be of imagemacgik, make sure you have the needed path of imagemagick in your PATH, type PATH in the cmd and search for the imagemagick dir. oh, and if you want discard that problem, use the script inside the imagemagick dir.

Comment: I've updated the code of my answer, take a look at the first command.

Comment: Yes, the ImageMagick directory is in the PATH. It still does not work. The PUSHD addition doesn't help either. But when I move the BAT to IM dir it works though! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The set command won't work if enclosed in parentheses. Also changed to REM instead of double quotes for comments.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Drag and drop a folder of images on the BAT-file.
REM A 

REM Set directory to that of dragged file
Set Dir=%~dp1

REM Create the output folder if don't exist
MKDIR "%~dp0modified" 2>NUL

REM Set maximium image height
SET /A "newHeight=780"

REM Set portrate extent width
SET /A "portrateWidth=585"

REM Read all the png and jpg images from the directory
FOR %%f IN ("%Dir%*.tif" "%Dir%*.jpg") DO (

REM Set the variable width to the image width
For /F %%# in ('identify -ping -format "%%[fx:w]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "width=%%#")

REM Set the variable height to the image height
For /F %%# in ('identify -ping -format "%%[fx:h]" "%%f"') Do (SET /A "height=%%#")

REM Check if the photo is portrate or landscape and run the relavant code
IF  !height! LSS !width!  (
    convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!newHeight! "%~dp0modified\%%~nf.jpg"
) ELSE (

REM Only resize if height is over 780
    IF  !height! LSS !newHeight! (
        REM Calculation for portrate extent width
        SET /A "newWidth=!height! * 3/4"
        convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!height! -background blue -gravity center -extent !newWidth!x!height! "%~dp0modified\%%~nf.jpg"
    ) ELSE (
        convert "%%f" -trim -resize x!newHeight! -background blue -gravity center -extent !portrateWidth!x!newHeight! "%~dp0modified\%%~nf.jpg"
        )
    )
)

PAUSE&EXIT
```

Comment: The main issue with your script was that wasn't using the correct working directory. Note that you can also eliminate the backslash in the variable %Dir% by using cd /d %Dir% or chdir /d %Dir%. The way you set up the script, if you drag a single file into it, it should find and process the other tif and jpg files where that file was located.

Comment: Your script probably worked before because it was located in the same directory as the image files.